# Assumptions in Schauder Fixed Point Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

I have a - maybe slightly stupid - question about the Schauder-Fixed-Point Theorem.

The formulation I have in mind is:

> Let $A$ be a closed, convex, nonempty subset in a Banach space $(X,\|\cdot\|)$, and $T \colon A \rightarrow A$ be a continuous, compact mapping. Then $T$ has a fixed point.

So my question is: When the assumptions are speaking about a subset, does it mean $A \subseteq X$ or $A \subsetneq X$?

Specifically, could I take
$X = L^2(\Omega)$ and $A = L^2(\Omega)$,
since then $A \subseteq X$ is closed in $X$, convex and nonempty, and conclude for a continuous map $T \colon L^2(\Omega) \rightarrow H^1(\Omega)$ by compact embedding $H^1(\Omega) \hookrightarrow L^2(\Omega)$ the existence of a fixed point in this situation?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Regarding your last example; every point is a fixed point of that embedding (without appealing to any compactness).